# Where can I Find position vs time data for the star S2?

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy

Does anyone here know where I can find the actual position versus time data for the orbit of the star S2 around the supermassive black hole Sagittarius A*? I have tried googling it with all possible queries imaginable yet I cannot get the tabulated data. It must exist because I have seen it plotted. I can't believe it is hidden behind a pay wall. I thought the data would be easy to find, bit it isn't. I just thought it would be fun to calculate the motion and overlay the calculation with the data.

Comment: Wikipedia has the orbital parameters from which you can calculate the orbit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2_(star)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested, I think I have found the data, see here:

https://iopscience.iop.org/1538-4357/707/2/L114/suppdata/apjl334146t1_mrt.txt